# Does an executable need so file even after it is linked during the creation?

Tags: shared-libraries, executable, dynamic-linking, .so

I have started looking into the concepts of linking libraries with exes and working in Linux machine. I'm struggling to understand the concept of linking so files with executables.

```
app:$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) app.o app_dep.o -L . -ldynamic -Wl,-rpath . \
                        -o app
```

I'm trying to create an executable app with the above lines in makefile. I have to link it with a `libdynamic.so` file which exists in the working directory. So i used `-L` flag and `-rpath` to point to the directory and name of the so file. It worked and executable is created.

But when i tried to run the executable, it again complains that `libdynamic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

1. Why do i need it since i linked the sharedlibrary during the creation of executable itself?

If the answer to the question is "Yes, it is required to point to the lib even it is linked". How could i point to the folder where it presents during the execution of binary?

One way i found is using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Is there any other way to do without environment variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Why do i need it since i linked the sharedlibrary during the creation of executable itself?

Because linking against a shared library *does not* embed that shared library into the executable. That is the *main* difference between linking with a shared versus archive library.

> How could i point to the folder where it presents during the execution of binary?

There are no "folders" in UNIX. They are *directories*.

The correct link command to make an executable look in *current* directory is:

```
gcc -o app app.o ... -L. -ldynamic -Wl,-rpath=.
```

Note that in general it's a really bad idea to do so: your executable will or will not run depending on your *current* directory (or it may use different versions of `libdynamic.so` depending on which directory you are in).

Your link command should have worked if you invoked `app` in the directory with `libdynamic.so` present (i.e. if you invoked it like `./app`), but not if you used `/path/to/app` (and were not in the same directory).

A significantly better approach is to do this:

```
gcc -o app app.o ... -L. -ldynamic -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'
```

That tells the `app` binary to look for `libdynamic.so` in the same directory in which `app` is located, regardless of your current directory.